# Excel - remove characters after a specific character

Tags: excel

I have colum B with values:

0015-04D-SEAW
0015-ADLKM-SPOK
0015-D-CURR
0016-01N-BOIL
etc.

How can I remove all characters after second dash and the second dash itself as well, it should look like this:

0015-04D
0015-ADLKM
0015-D
0016-01N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One dirty solution would be to convert text to columns delimited by `-` and then to concatenate the first two columns separated by `-`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `B1` contains `0015-04D-SEAW`

This would do : `=IFERROR(MID(B1,1,FIND("-",B1,FIND("-",B1,1)+1)-1),B1)`

Result : 0015-04D